# How to reuse modelling bases for the Stratasys uPrint SE Plus?

Tags: material, build-plate

It's criminal how wasteful the Stratsys uPrint SE Plus is with it's 'one use' modelling bases. Is there a reliable way to re purpose them? I have tried ethanol and acetone, but not had any luck.

Comment: Hi, when talking about "one use modelling bases", do you mean the *rafts* created underneath each model as it is printed?

Comment: Hello, I mean the black modelling bases that the ABS is printed onto. With this model of machine they are difficult to reuse as the support material laid down leaves a scar.

Answer (score 4):

What I tried and worked is to apply water based normal Glue-stick on the tray and with few drops of water distribute it evenly across the tray surface, let it dry and then you are good to go!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. What sort of glue do you mean? Glue that you would use to stick paper together with?

Comment: @JPD, although I do not know the exact brand that Mohammad use, I know that [UHU Glue Sticks](http://www.uhu.com/en/products/paper-glues.html) are fairly commonly used. Different glue stick give somewhat different results, so you might want to try a few different types.

Comment: The brands I tried are Scholastic glue stick and Staples glue stick both gave the same results. Worth mentioning that it is easier to remove the part when the tray is cool.I plan to experiment with the Aquanet hairspray next week.

Answer (score 3):

People have done quite a bit of experimenting with reusing Mojo build plates over the years. The uPrint is likely similar. Basically a different adhesion layer is placed on the bed that has easier release. BuildTak has been used successfully. Gluestick or hairspray such as Aquanet will work and are water soluble for easier removal post-print.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BuildTak looks interesting. Excuse my ignorance, but would you put a layer of this on top of the modelling base before printing? Then remove the print from it, clean it and re-use? 

Also do there have to be some manual adjustments to nozzle height etc. due to the added layer?

Lastly, how do machines that require calibration points (such as the uPrint SE Plus) deal with having a non-native surface to calibrate to?

Comment: Right, you put the adhesion layer on the modeling base before printing. That allows the raft to come off easier.  If the added layer is thin enough, it won't interfere with the normal raft building process. But I'm not specifically familiar with your printer, so it may take some experimenting. Obviously this isn't supported by Stratasys, because they want to make money on consumables.

Comment: Ryan, can you let us know the source for 'people have done...' to dig a bit deeper in their experience, - temerature changes and adhesion results for example? Thanks in advance

Comment: Search for Mojo posts by vrfx and EnginWiz on the 3D Printer Tips Tricks and Reviews Google Group. They've both posted about it a few times. Can't find links from my phone though.

Answer (score 1):

By oversight in training, the operators of one of our UPrint SE Plus printers was simply placing the tray in the bath with the printed part.  After it was in the bath, all support material was removed and they dried and reused the tray.  This process was used for months before it was discovered, and they used the same tray for many prints.  Has anyone else tried this?

Answer (score 1):

I've done the bit where you place the tray and part into the bath. Upon completion of dissolving, I then used a little dawn dish-soap to clean the tray, let it dry. I have access and used DI water for the hand washing (without any scrub or pad, just my hands). The trays worked fine. 
Someone else took over for a bit. I think they were trying to clean with Vinegar, and the trays have all turned white (not sure if that is from this?). So, they aren't being reused.
I've started being a bit strategic with some print jobs. I'll print in one corner, then use cutters to remove the support without damaging the tray. Then I'll print on that tray in a different corner.